# Play / Pause when mouseover mouseout / mouse hover on off JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, autoplay, mousehover

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (jQuery('.lwp-video-autoplay .et_pb_video_box').length !== 0) {
        jQuery('.lwp-video-autoplay .et_pb_video_box').find('video').prop('muted', true);
        jQuery(".lwp-video-autoplay .et_pb_video_box").find('video').attr('loop', 'loop');
        jQuery(".lwp-video-autoplay .et_pb_video_box").find('video').attr('playsInline', '');
        jQuery(".lwp-video-autoplay .et_pb_video_box").each(function() {
            jQuery(this).find('video').get(0).play();
        });
        jQuery('.lwp-video-autoplay .et_pb_video_box').find('video').removeAttr('controls');
    }
});
```

I am trying to create a video that only plays when you hover over it and pauses when you hover off.

The video shouldn't have an controls. I've found this tutorial https://www.learnhowwp.com/how-to-autoplay-videos-in-divi-video-module-and-hide-controls/ which has got to the point of autoplaying the video.

I would just like to have the video paused orginally and only start whenever I hover over it. Here is the code provided that has worked so far

I've been searching extensively through google + stackoverflow but whatever I try doesn't seem to work within the code I already have. Also trying other examples doesn't work for me. I am not technical so any advance would be much appreciated

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring that mess posted in OP I made an minimal working example:

1. The event handler handles both 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' events
2. The `Event.type` Event property is used to determine which event is currently triggered.
3. Note `this` is used instead of `$(this)`. `$(this)` is a reference to a jQuery Object which doesn't recognize most JavaScript methods like `.play()` or `.pause()`. `this` is a reference to a JavaScript Object which does not recognize jQuery methods but it recognizes JavaScript methods like `.play()` and `.pause()`.
4. <s>Since the example is in an iframe, you must focus by clicking that area first. After clicking, try hovering over and out of the video.</s>
5. Added `[muted]` property so it responds to pointer events properly. See VC.One's comment below.

```js
$('video').on('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
  const evt = e.type;
  if (evt === 'mouseover') {
    this.play();
  }
  if (evt === 'mouseout') {
    this.pause();
  }
});
```

```css
video {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<video src='https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs2s3.mp4' width='200' muted></video>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should add the `muted` property to your video tag setup. Otherwise we have to click the white space around the video before it responds to any rollover. With "muted" it should autoplay on rollover without needing a "must first click on page" situation.